# duplicate $.ajax request does not fire callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I make the exact same ajax request in the callback from the first request, the callback for the second request does not fire.

```
function doCall(){  
console.log('1');
$.ajax(
    'InfoRequest.cgi?reqType=rxChanNames&deviceName=Ultimo-0700b9'
)
.always(function(d){
    console.log('success1');        
    $.ajax(
        'InfoRequest.cgi?reqType=rxChanNames&deviceName=Ultimo-0700b9'
    )
    .always(function(d2){
        console.log('success2');                        
    });             
});
}
```

The second call is made, and a 200 responds from the server but 'success2' is never printed.
The response for the request is JSON:

```
{"data":[],"status":"wserrortimeout"}
```

If I change the second request to

```
'InfoRequest.cgi?reqType=rxChanNames&deviceName=Ultimo-0700b8'
```

then it fires the callback.

Before anyone asks why I want to do this, what I have outlined here is a much simplified version of what I am actually doing that still demonstrates the problem.  The application is on embedded hardware which sometimes responds with an error in which case the request needs to be retried.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: why dont you check for the error and then make the request again

Comment: That is what I am doing in the actual application.  The same thing happens.  If there is a different request in-between, then everything is fine but if the same request is made in a row, there's no callbacks firing for the second request.

Comment: You can check the network tab in browser development tools. Is the second request actually done and is there a response?

Comment: The fact that changing a parameter makes the call work leads me to believe it's a cache issue.. try using `cache: false` in the ajax calls, which appends a parameter with a timestamp, to see if that works.

Comment: @JasonP adding `cache:false` works!  This is a strange issue though don't you think?  The request is really made, does not say "from cache" or anything, but the callback does not fire.  Interestingly, it works ok in IE.

Comment: That is odd. Without more information, I'd have to guess it's something about the browser on the embedded hardware.

Comment: If you add as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: @njc I guess because your posted code doesn't reflect exactly your original one and that you bind ajax callback after the actual request has completed

Comment: For clarity, the SERVER is embedded hardware, the browser is chrome on Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that changing a parameter makes the call work leads me to believe it's a cache issue.

Use `cache:false` in the ajax parameters to prevent caching.

Answer (score -1):

There is no issue in you javascript.. You may have to look the CGI code if you are forwarding the request to some where else or some how the you are not sending the response back.